# What does this limit indicate?

Tags: number-theory, limits, riemann-zeta

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \zeta(x)-\zeta(x)^{-1}-\zeta(x)^2 = -1$$

What does this limit indicate?

Comment: Where did you find this limit? Was it really mentioned without interpretation or anything?

Comment: I had this formula for $\zeta(0)$ and decided to find out it it translated to the other values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That $\zeta(x)\to1$ when $x\to+\infty$, period.